# How Do I Grant Permissions to Replace a Function?

Tags: db2, permissions, functions

I am getting the following error message (when trying to enable `NOSQL` in `DB2 10.5`, although I don't think that's really the issue):

> Error code: -551 DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501,
>   SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN;REPLACE FUNCTION; SYSTOOLS.JSON_VAL2, DRIVER=4.17.29
>
> An error occurred during database object creation, rolling back

The `DB2ADMIN` user already has the following permissions:

```
grant DBADM, SECADM, ACCESSCTRL, DATAACCESS ON DATABASE TO USER db2admin
```

I cannot find the `GRANT` command that I need to use to enable `DB2ADMIN` to replace the function. Sorry, I'm not a DBA, so I just need the exact command I'd need to enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, whatever you are doing tries to `CREATE OR REPLACE` the function `SYSTOOLS.JSON_VAL2`. To replace any object the ID performing the operation must be the owner of that object, that is, the same ID that issued the very first `CREATE` statement.

You have several options:

1. Use the `TRANSFER OWNERSHIP` statement to change the function owner. `SECADM` can do that.
2. Determine the current owner (`SELECT OWNER FROM SYSCAT.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINENAME = 'JSON_VAL2' AND ROUTINESCHEMA = 'SYSTOOLS'`) and perform your task while logged in as that user.
3. Drop the object explicitly, for which `DBADM` is sufficient, before performing your task.